# How to stop send Welcome email to customer in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to stop send welcome email to customer in magento 1.7.0.2. Please let me know any solution as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a valid question without many obvious answers. An inexperienced Magento developer would struggle with this task.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately this is not a simple task and there is no way to do it via the Magento Admin.

There are a few places this welcome email could get kicked off from, but you could stop it at the Customer Model level. The function that does the work is Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendNewAccountEmail (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php line 587)

You will need to create a new module with a configuration setting to disable the email and then extend the customer model method, reading the setting.

Something like this (untested code, use at your own risk):

In your Module's system.xml:

```
<sections>
        <customer>
            <groups>
                <create_account>
                    <send_welcome_email translate="label">
                        <label>Send Welcome Email?</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>65</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </auto_group_assign>                    
                </send_welcome_email>                   
            </groups>
        </customer>
</sections>
```

Extend the Customer Model. In your Module, Model/Customer.php

```
class YourModule_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{   
    public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
    {   
        if ( ! Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/create_account/send_welcome_email') ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $types = array(
            'registered'   => self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is disabled
            'confirmed'    => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is enabled
            'confirmation' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // email with confirmation link
        );
        if (!isset($types[$type])) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wrong transactional account email type'));
        }

        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
        }

        $this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl), $storeId);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: sad that you took the time to write out this rather well thought out answer, however the OP of this question has not been on SO even once since the day he posted the question. Despite even including "Please let me know any solution as soon as possible" (which I think is rude to say "as soon as possible" when reaching out to the community for free help) in his question.

Comment: I was looking for the same solution and google led me here. After I figured it out for myself, I figured I'd leave my solution here for others who found the question, not for the original asker.

Comment: Thank you @BenTruby for doing exactly what you did :D